# Checking if any two subsequent rows have the same value

Tags: r, if-statement, tidyverse

I have the following dataset:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | EuropeGreece |
| 5 | 7 | EuropeGreece |
| 7 | 11 | EuropeBelgium |
| 6 | 12 | EuropeBelgium |
| 9 | 13 | EuropeCrotia |

What I would like to achieve is that I would like R to check if the two values in column C are the same, then I would like to compare if the second value in Column A is higher than first value in Column A and the same for Column B. If the values in Column C are not the same, then I would like to get "N/A" rather than FALSE because the comparison in column A and B could produce FALSE.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You only have two rows. That is not quite easy to replicate. Have like 5 rows, with different values and then we can help

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

Use a series of `ifelse` statements to:

- Check if the next row in 'C' matches, if not, return NA.
- If TRUE, then check if the next next row in A and B are greater, if not, return FALSE.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(
  A = c(3,5,7,6,9),
  B = c(6,7,11,12,13),
  C = c(paste0("Europe",c("Greece","Greece","Belgium","Belgium","Croatia")))
)

df %>%
  mutate(cond = ifelse(C == lead(C),
                  ifelse(A < lead(A) & B < lead(B), TRUE, FALSE), 
                    NA))
```

```
  A  B             C  cond
1 3  6  EuropeGreece  TRUE
2 5  7  EuropeGreece    NA
3 7 11 EuropeBelgium FALSE
4 6 12 EuropeBelgium    NA
5 9 13 EuropeCroatia    NA
```

Answer (score 1):

[Jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11564586/jamie)s answer gives `NA` for the second/last of each group member of C. If the data is indeed ordered in the manner that gives meaning (is there a column of dates that order the data? Otherwise the question gives no sense as the order of the rows are arbitrary), good, otherwise ...

`lead` returns the next value for the column arranged in a given order, and does not discriminate whether the next value is in the same group or not.

You can group and arrange your data in the manner that best suits you.

Consider:

```
# A dataframe where the data is not ordered
df <- data.frame(
    A = c(3,5,7,6,9),
    B = c(6,7,11,12,13),
    C = c(paste0("Europe",c("Greece","Belgium","Greece", "Belgium","Croatia")))
)

df %>%
    mutate(cond = ifelse(C == lead(C),
                         ifelse(A < lead(A) & B < lead(B), TRUE, FALSE), 
                         NA))

  A  B             C cond
1 3  6  EuropeGreece   NA
2 7 11 EuropeBelgium   NA
3 5  7  EuropeGreece   NA
4 6 12 EuropeBelgium   NA
5 9 13 EuropeCroatia   NA
```

- I want to find the rows where there is more than one member of each C AND where both A and B are the highest in the group:

```
df %>% 
    group_by(C) %>% 
    mutate(cond = case_when(n() < 2 ~ NA,
                            A == max(A, na.rm = TRUE) &
                                B == max(B, na.rm = TRUE) 
                            ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
    ungroup()

      A     B C             cond 
1     3     6 EuropeGreece  FALSE
2     7    11 EuropeBelgium FALSE
3     5     7 EuropeGreece  TRUE 
4     6    12 EuropeBelgium FALSE
5     9    13 EuropeCroatia NA
```

- My data indeed has only a maximum of two members for each group of C and is ordered by date.

```
df <- data.frame(
    dato = c("2021/01/01", "2021/01/01", "2022/01/01", "2022/01/01", "2022/01/01"),
    A = c(3,7,5,6,9),
    B = c(6,11,7,12,13),
    C = c(paste0("Europe",c("Greece","Belgium","Greece", "Belgium","Croatia")))
)

# Well, the same code, except for `arrange` and 
# limiting to exactly 2 members of C
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(C) %>% 
    arrange(dato) %>% 
    mutate(cond = case_when(n() == 2 ~ NA,
                            A == max(A, na.rm = TRUE) &
                                B == max(B, na.rm = TRUE) 
                            ~ TRUE,
                            TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>% 
    ungroup()

# print it arranged by country and date
df2 %>% 
    arrange(C, dato)
```

Comment: `lead` would also work within each group, and is really good if your data is ordered - lets say to calculate change over time.